# Why does FreeRTOS use short and long type, but not int type?

Tags: c, freertos

From *Using the FreeRTOS Real Time Kernel - Standard Edition, p143*, I noticed that:

> int types are never used – only long and short

I would like to know why, but I find no answer in its official site and no result after google.

**Update 08/31:**

Maybe my question is not so clear, in short, I just wonder that why FreeRTOS defines `BaseType_t` as `long` instead of `int`(and other FreeRTOS defined types are never use `int`, too). From its [Coding-Standard-and-Style-Guide](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Coding-Standard-and-Style-Guide.html#DataTypes) page, it said that:

> BaseType_t
>
> This is defined to be the most efficient, natural, type for the architecture. For example, on a 32-bit architecture BaseType_t will be defined to be a 32-bit type. On a 16-bit architecture BaseType_t will be defined to be a 16-bit type. If BaseType_t is define to char then particular care must be taken to ensure signed chars are used for function return values that can be negative to indicate an error.

From the above description, I think `int` is more suitable than `long`, since `int` is always conform to the architecture's word size.

Answer (score 3):

The [FreeRTOS coding standard](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Coding-Standard-and-Style-Guide.html#DataTypes) disagrees with your reference.

The actual requirement is that you use typedefs that have been defined by RTOS, or the integer typedefs found in `stdint.h`, such as `uint32_t`. Normally, the types found in `stdint.h` are acceptable, because the size of those integers do not vary on different architectures.

Comment: Sorry but I don't find disagrees between the link you supplied and my reference, please say my updates above

Comment: @Cifer: Quoting you: _From the above description, I think int is more suitable than long, since int is always conform to the architecture's word size._  That's just not true.

Answer (score 0):

Not an official answer by any means, by I would suppose they wanted to make sure their types are clearly defined, and therefore decided on 3 int types: `char` (`uint8_t`), `short` (`unit16_t`) and `long` (`uint32_t`). This way any confusion as to what's the size of `int` is avoided.

Comment: None of the types you mentioned has to have that corresponding fixed size type.

Comment: @black according to [FreeRTOS  Coding Standard and Style Guide](http://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS-Coding-Standard-and-Style-Guide.html) these are clearly defined fixed size types. They just had to come up with 3 names for the 3 types, and found that `int` would be too confusing to use for one of them.